# prove that if $n$ is odd then $n^3-n$ is divisible by 8

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We know that $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Our goal is to prove that if $n$ is odd then $n^3-n$ is divisible by 8. This is what I have done so far:

Assume it holds for for some odd numbers that we will denote as $k$. 
$$k^3-k$$
Now we need to prove that it holds for $k+2$.

$$(k+2)^3-(k+2)$$
Expanding the equation gives:
$$k^3+6k^2+11k+6$$

I am not sure how to proceed after this step. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start by writing your odd number $k$ as $k = 2n-1$.  Then, expand out.

Comment: Use $k=2n+1$ also

Comment: You are on the right track. Subtract $k^3-k$ and rework the result.

Comment: Show that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
n^3 \equiv n \pmod{8}
\end{eqnarray*}
For each of the $4$ odd classes.

Comment: Note that it's essential to somehow *use* the fact that $n$ is odd in your inductive step.  There are some even numbers for which $n^3-n$ is divisible by $8$ (namely, multiples of $8$), so if you didn't use the fact that $n$ is odd, it would follow that the statement is true for all sufficiently large $n$, but that's not true.

Answer (score 5):

$$n^3-n=n(n^2-1)=(n-1)n(n+1)$$
If $n$ is odd then $n\pm1$ are even, but for any two consecutive even numbers, one of them must be divisible by $4$. Hence $n^3-n$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that

$$(k+2)^3-(k+2)=k^3-k+6k^2+12k+6=k^3-k+6(k+1)^2.$$

By hypothesis the first two terms form a multiple of $8$, then $6$ is even and $k+1$ is even.

Comment: how do we know that $6(k+1)^2$ is divisible by 8?

Comment: $k+1$ is even so $(k+1)^2$ is divisible by $4$ and $6$ is divisible by $2$. So their product is divisible by $8$.

Comment: @StashuKozlowski: try a few values and you will understand.

Answer (score 2):

$n\;\; is\;\; odd \;\;implies$ $\;\;n=2k+1$, $\;\;k\;\; a \;\;integer\;\; number$.

$n^3 - n=(2k+1)^3$$-(2k+1)$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=$ $(8k^3+12k^2+6k+1)$$-(2k+1)$$\\$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=$ $8k^3+12k^2+6k+1-2k-1$$\\$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=$ $8k^3+12k^2+4k$$\\$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=$ $8k^3+4(3k^2+k)$$\\$     $\;\;\;  (1)$

Now:

If k is even, $(3k^2+k)$ is even (the sum of two even numbers is even)

If k is odd, $(3k^2+k)$ is even (the sum of two odd numbers is even)

This means that $(3k^2+k)$ is even and can rewrite like 2t, t is a integer number.

$4(3k^2+k)$$=4(2t)$$=8t$

Then (1)     $\;\;8k^3+4(3k^2+k)= 8k^3 + 8t=8(k^3+t)$

And $8(k^3+t)$ is divisible by 8